# Bootstrap tooltip with a link to another page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, tooltip

The basic syntax to create a tooltip is:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="first tooltip">hover over me</a>
```

In my web page I need to use a tooltip in a link, I tried to change the href="#" to my link, but the tooltip doen't work. I tried to change for some thing like this:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="first tooltip">
    <a href="mylink">Link</a>
</a>
```

But only the link works, the tooltip doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you can't, but you can use this tool:

http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/any-html.html